# Prove that $\lim\limits_{\omega\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\pi t}=\delta(t)$ where $\delta(t)$ is the impulse function.

Tags: calculus, analysis, signal-processing, dirac-delta

Prove that $$\lim_{\omega\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\pi t}=\delta(t)$$
where $\delta(t)$ is the impulse function.

This is a property that our teacher mentioned without strict proof. I've already tried to proof
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{t}=\pi(\omega>0)$$
But I have some trouble connecting this equation to the upper property.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Comment: Hint: use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#nascent_delta_function) with $\eta(t)=\frac{\sin t}{\pi t},\,\varepsilon=1/\omega$.

Answer (score 4):

We have to show that $\forall \varphi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$: $\lim\limits_{\omega \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\pi t} [\varphi]=\delta[\varphi]$, ( $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ is a space of test functions, f.e. the Schwartz-Space). More explicitly:
$$
\forall \varphi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}): \quad \lim\limits_{\omega \rightarrow \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\pi t} \varphi(t)\ dt=\varphi(0)
$$
This follows by the substitution $u:=\omega t$, then above expression turns into:
$$
\lim\limits_{\omega \rightarrow \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(u)}{\pi u} \varphi(u/\omega)\ du=
$$
Using dominated convergence we find:
$$
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim\limits_{\omega \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin(u)}{\pi u} \varphi(u/\omega)\ du= \varphi(0)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(u)}{\pi u}\ du=\varphi(0)
$$

**Edit:**
Maybe to further clarify: What you‘re trying to prove is not an equality of functions in the usual sense. Normally two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are equal if $\forall x : f(x)=g(x)$, but your „impulse function“ $\delta(x)$ doesn’t have defined values, particularly not for $x=0$. To deal with this problem in mathematics two functions of this kind (distributions) are said to be equal if $\int f(x)\varphi(x)dx= \int g(x)\varphi(x)dx$, for all $\varphi$ that „behave well enough“. (It actually gets even trickier in your case because you’re considering a limit of distributions, and to talk about limits your distribution space needs to be equipped with a topology and so on but these are just details that probably aren’t relevant here)

Comment: nice answer but you want to be careful with your $du$ and your $dt$ (and maybe emphasise that you need to apply to test functions as you have done, it's likely op is trying to prove this as an identity of function equality!)

Comment: Yes, you’re right I edited it, thank you:)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clarification! That helps a lot:)

Comment: But I still have some trouble with the Dominated convergence step (since I didn't lean Real Variable Functions systematically): When using DCT, am I going to find a integrable function $g$ which satisfies $\forall \omega |f(\omega)|\leqslant g$? In this situation how can I find the function $g$?

Comment: Glad I could help:) If you didn‘t have an introduction into measure theory they probably don‘t expect you to justify the swap of $\lim$ and integral. But as you say you would do it by finding such a $g$. In this case the g is given by $\frac{\sin(u)}{\pi u} \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} (\varphi(x))$, this is integrable because $\varphi$ „behaves well“ and therefore $\sup _{x \in \mathbb{R}} (\varphi(x)) < \infty$.